# How to search BigQuery query files for specific text?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to find a specific query I wrote three months ago that was used to generate a table.
I can't remember the name of the file where the query was run.

How can I search through the hundreds of saved query files I have to just return the files which match my search terms?
The Explorer 'Type to search' function only searches file names.

[image: BigQuery Explorer Type to search feature]

Comment: two options, one being in biquery sql workspace, look in project history or personal history. if you can't find here, search in cloud logging

Answer (score 0):

If you need to locate a specific query you worked on in a certain project, you can utilize the project history option located at the bottom of the page. To narrow down the search, you can apply filters such as `created on` or a combination of `created after` and `created before` to limit the results to the queries you have written.

Additionally, if you remember specific details about the query, such as certain naming conventions or table names, it is recommended to include those details in the search bar. This will further refine the search results and assist in finding the desired query more efficiently.

[image: project history in bigquery]